# Powerlifting and limited time

Tags: powerlifting

I'm a powerlifter since 2016. If I'll have less time in the future due to work, would it be better to workout early in the morning or before sleep?

Comment: I feel like the only answer to this is "it depends". Do you have more context? Are you naturally a morning person? Do you feel more energetic in the evening? etc.

Comment: I agree, this largely depends on diet, sleep habits, what kind of work you are doing, etc.

Comment: I also agree with the comments, but take in mind that it may not be the best idea working out before sleep, especially if you are talking about powerlifting because it puts a strain on the nervous system. However if you feel confortable working out before sleep and you don't have side effect in your sleep schedule (continuous awakenings during the night) there is nothing stopping you from working out before bedtime